# In which episode did Worf's say his famous phrase about humanity?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification, worf

In which episode (and in which moment) of *Star Trek: The Next Generation* did Worf say his famous line?

> People have a lot to talk, yet little to say.

I can only recall that it was *probably* halfway through the series (3rd or 4th season) and that it was *most likely* the first episode of a two-episode story.

Comment: Worf's famous phrase, or [Benjamin Franklin's](https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Franklin/01-03-02-0103)?

Comment: @mattdm - "*Half Wits talk much but say little.*"

Comment: @Valorum Yes. From the answer, the actual line is very similar to Poor Richard's, except "some people use humor as a shield" instead of "half wits". This line is either a direct reference to Franklin, or else a play on the aphorism without the writer being aware of its source.

Comment: @mattdn the original is by Benjamin Franklin - the famous Klingon pundit.

Comment: @LSerni One can never truly appreciate *Poor Richard's Almanack* until you've read it in the original Klingon.

Comment: @mattdm: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3E8lbTCIAIRTT-.jpg

Comment: @mattdm Worf, a Star Trek's character, said this in "The Emissary", a Star Trek's episode. So, this is "his famous pharse". Period. In which part of my question I suggest that he (or actually script writer behind this episode) is the _original_ author of this text? If looking for original author, I'd rather ask on History.se, not on SF&F, right? :>

Comment: @LSerni [Franklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_(TV_series)) said this first? That famous turtle? Didn't know he is named Benjamin! :>

Comment: @trejder I doubt that is this line is "famous" as "Worf's phrase" in any way. It's a phrase that was _already famous_ that Worf uttered a variation of.

Comment: @mattdm Objection noted! :>

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is [TNG: The Emissary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Emissary_(episode)). Note that he's talking about *people* rather than humans.

> **K'EHLEYR**: *Worf, you're the perfect Klingon. The ultimate minimalist. Talk to me.*
>
> **WORF:** *I've noted that some people use humour as a shield. They talk much, yet say little*.
>
> <sub><sup>[transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/146.htm)</sup></sub>